# how can I wait for the Initialize() finish then execute the code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code needs to wait until the Initialize() then can be execute.
I use WaitForSeconds(1.0f) until Initialize() like below , but it saw no good solution.

```
    IEnumerator waiuntilInit()
    {
        Initialize();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        dosomeThing();
    }
```

how can I wait for the Initialize() finish then execute the code?

```
void waitInit(){
  wait  Initialize()
  dosomeThing();
}
```

```
Initialize()
{
     var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
     builder.Configure<IGooglePlayConfiguration>().SetDeferredPurchaseListener(OnDeferredPurchase);
     builder.Configure<IGooglePlayConfiguration>().SetQueryProductDetailsFailedListener(MyAction);
     builder.AddProduct(productId, ProductType.Subscription);
     UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
};
```

Comment: You can make an asynchronous call to `Initialize()` and make the `dosomething()` await, till the former is not completed its execution

Comment: Consider using `async/await` instead of coroutines.  Apart from being the contemporary way to perform async operations, knowing _when the task is complete_ is a free steak knife.

Comment: 1. using async/await not coroutine.

Comment: Well what exactly does `Initialize();` do? .. as it stands all methods by default in c# are executed sequential .. so `dosomeThing` would never run before `Initilaize` is finished .... Using the phrases you already almost had there is the mentioned [`async` and `await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: When you call any method, the execution will not continue untill entire method have being executed. So you don't need to wait method execution. Except cases when you use asynchronous programming or `yield` instructions. So what is in your `Initialize` method, that you want to wait?

Comment: @derHugo my initialize is init the   UnityPurchasing

Comment: @Nikolai my initialize is init the UnityPurchasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `WaitUntil` inside your coroutine.

The code sample for Purchaser script for unity purchasing comes with a method (at least I don't remember writting it myself), that checks if it was initialized:

```
public bool IsInitialized()
{
    // Only say we are initialized if both the Purchasing references are set.
    return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
}
```

You now got a condition, that you should wait for, now it's time for writting a corotuine:

```
IEnumerator waiuntilInit()
{
    Initialize();
    yield return new WaitUntil( () => IsInitialized());
    dosomeThing();
}
```

If you don't like corotutines, you can apply the same idea of waiting with task execution until both m_StoreController and m_StoreExtensionProvider are not null using async/await or doing it in update (with appropriate flags and timers to ensure you do it once) if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested coroutine to accomplish this.  Make the Initialize() method also a couroutine then 'yield' from within the first one.  I've checked the log output below and it works in the order you are looking for.  Good luck :)

```
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(waitUntilInit());
    }

    IEnumerator waitUntilInit()
    {
        Debug.Log("1 Wait until Init");
        yield return Initialize();
        Debug.Log("4 Do Something else now");
    }

    IEnumerator Initialize()
    {
        Debug.Log("2 Initialize Start");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        Debug.Log("3 Initialize Done");
    }
```